# gunicorn Connection in use for python flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I recently changed my Heroku Python Flask app from the '*small application*' format to the 'simple package' format based from [flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/) (De-coupling everything in `app.py` into separate subdirectories)

The application runs correctly using

```
> python runserver.py
```

However, executing

```
gunicorn runserver:app --log-file=-
```

outputs:

```
"Starting gunicorn .... connection in use error" (loops forever)
```

My runserver.py configuration is:

```
 from re3 import app
 app.run(debug=True)
```

__init__.py configuration:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
import views
```

view.py configuration:

```
from re3 import app
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

What is changing in the two executions?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you run your application anytime `runserver` is imported. You only want that to happen when it's executed directly.

```
from re3 import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Edit:

The usage for gunicorn is

```
$ gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
```

When you run gunicorn, it imports `APP_MODULE`. In your case, you've specified `runserver`. So while you don't import it yourself, gunicorn does. And before gunicorn can run `app`, `runserver` runs it.

Comment: Thanks. runserver.py is never imported but I see your point. I added the changes but the problem is still there.