# Flask raises `Address already in use` running with a WSGI server such as Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run my app with Gunicorn. However, Flask raises `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` while Gunicorn is starting, then Gunicorn shuts down. How do I serve the app with Gunicorn?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

app.run(debug=True)
```

```
gunicorn app:app
```

```
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21965] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21965] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (21965)
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21965] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21968] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21968
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21969] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/david/Projects/py36/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 691, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21968] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21968)
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21965] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-02-19 21:09:50 -0800] [21965] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I tried [gunicorn Connection in use for python flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145728/gunicorn-connection-in-use-for-python-flask) and [error: [Errno 98] Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356224/error-errno-98-address-already-in-use) but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're using Gunicorn (or any production WSGI server), so you don't want to use the Flask dev server. But you're calling `app.run` unconditionally. Gunicorn starts, binds the address, then imports your app, which calls `app.run` and tries to start its own server. But the address is already in use by Gunicorn.

Move `app.run` into a guard block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Or preferably remove it completely, since you should be using the `flask` command to run the dev server, as described in the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).